# XYZ geo.admin.ch map doesn't work with qgis 3.0

Tags: python-3.x, leaflet, tiles, qgis, jstilemap

I'm new to XYZ tile maps.

I'm trying to add an XYZ map from geo.admin.ch the well known swiss map available to all bordering states.

Here I've found the [leaflet link](https://wmts20.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe/default/current/3857/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.jpeg).

Here's the code

```
var map = new L.Map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
  continuousWorld: true,
  worldCopyJump: false
});
var url = 'https://wmts20.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe/default/current/3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg';
var tilelayer = new L.tileLayer(url);
map.addLayer(tilelayer);
map.setView(L.latLng(46.57591, 7.84956), 8);
```

and the [API page](http://api3.geo.admin.ch/index.html)

Comment: Do you have any error message? Something that is specifically failing?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread, but for historical purposes:

- You are not allowed to use WMTS from geo.admin.ch for desktop systems, only WMS, see [official docs](https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/products/geoservice/swisstopo_geoservices/WMTS_info)
- Even for WMS, you cannot use the basemaps for free, like Swisstopo Pixelkarte`, see [official docs](https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/products/geoservice/swisstopo_geoservices/swisstopoWMS). There is a credit system, with some map requests for free.

So, it's not an issue with the code (although I haven't checked your code).